# Function that takes two ShortUUIDs and outputs a consistently unique string for identification

Tags: python, hash, uuid

I'm trying to store a bidirectional relationship in a database and to minimise duplicity of storing two records per relationship, I'm trying to find a way to take two UUIDs in **either order** and return the same unique id regardless of which UUID was supplied first.

```
F(a,b) should return the same value as F(b,a)
```

Examples of ShortUUID output:

```
wpsWLdLt9nscn2jbTD3uxe
vytxeTZskVKR7C7WgdSP3d
```

Comment: More detail needed. Where do you want to compute `F`, in Python or in the database? Presumably, you want `F(a, b) != F(x, y)` if `{a, b} != {x, y}` as well?

Comment: @chepner Computation on the python side and yes the compositie ID needs to be unique if the primary IDs are different

Answer (score 2):

Could something like this work for you?

The function takes two strings as input, orders them, concatenates them into one string, encodes that string and finally returns the hashed result.

```
import hashlib


def F(a, b):
    data = ''.join(sorted([a, b])).encode()
    return hashlib.sha1(data).hexdigest()
```

The output is

```
>> a = 'string_1'
>> b = 'string_2'
>> print(F(a, b))
376598c12bb7949427f4c037070fff76fe932a66
>> print(F(b, a))
376598c12bb7949427f4c037070fff76fe932a66
```

Comment: Depending on whether @Joshua wants the resulting ID to trace back to the original two IDs or not, they could just return `''.join(sorted(a, b))`

Comment: @Andrew the resulting ID is always accessed with both original IDs supplied so reverse access is less important than collision aversion and keeping the resulting ID short

Comment: `join` and `sorted` is overkill if you know you only have two elements: `a+b if a < b else b + a`.

Comment: @chepner I was hoping there was a way to keep the composite key shorter, otherwise I could just store them in two separate columns

Answer (score 1):

Interesting! What do you think of this, that will retain your ShortUUID format?

```py
def F(a,b):
    l = (len(a)//2)+1
    each_half = zip(a[:l],b[:l]) if a < b else zip(b[:l],a[:l])
    return ''.join([x+y for x,y in (each_half)])[:len(a)]
```

The first line will ensure that F works also if you will change your ShortUUID to have an odd length.

The second line zip one char from the first half of each a and b, ordered.

The last will return the joined string, capped at the length of a

Just tried:

```py
a = 'wpsWLdLt9nscn2jbTD3uxe'
b = 'vytxeTZskVKR7C7WgdSP3d'
assert F(a,b) == F(b,a)
print(F(a,b)) # vwyptsxWeLTdZLstk9VnKs
```

Comment: This is an interesting take, any what is the chance of collision?

Comment: I think that's the same as the ShortUUID.
I can see 22 chars, taken from lower, upper and digits: 62 total.
It's 1 on 62 ** 22 = 1/2707803647802660400290261537185326956544

Comment: It's one decimal digit safer than MD5, that is 1/16**32